# Dragging a header column leaves unwanted white space

Tags: smartgwt

Is there a way for the column headers not leave whitespace on the rightside when you resize it by dragging? On the `smartclient`'s website: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#featured_grid_cell_widgets if you resize the header column by dragging it to the left side, there is much unwanted white space created on the right, is there way for smartGWT to adjust this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you enable horizontal auto-fitting, then resizing a column's width will similarly resize the width of the grid:

```
myGrid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.HORIZONTAL);
```

See the [Grids - Autofit - Columns](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_autofit_columns) sample.